# SQL autoincrement id with duplicate values and multiple column primary keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

```
CREATE TABLE Apps
(
    id int NOT NULL,
    company varChar(20) NOT NULL,
    name varChar(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT company_app_id PRIMARY KEY (id, company)
)

-------------------------------------
| id  | company      | name         |
-------------------------------------
|  1  | Google       | Google Maps  |
|  2  | Google       | Gmail        |
|  1  | Apple        | Safari       |
|  3  | Google       | Chrome       |
|  2  | Apple        | Pages        |
-------------------------------------
```

Is there a way in SQL to build the above table that allows it to autoincrement the id specific to the company? So, if the next entry is a Google app, it autoincrements the id to 4, and if the entry after that is an Apply app, it autoincrements the id to 2?

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I infer it's MySQL. The clue is `int(20)`.

Comment: You can but I don't see an advantage to it.  This can be a headache to manage.  Just use a regular auto increment field and then build this logic into a view if that's why you need it.

Comment: Your company name should be in its own table Company with an autoincrementing integer PK.  Your Apps table would then have CountryID as a FK referencing Company.

Comment: It's a design doc. The version of SQL has not been decided.

Leaning towards Aurora though.

Comment: sgeddes - Not sure how this would be build into a view. I'd have to retrieve every item for Google to calculate the actual id every time I really just wanted one item. Perhaps it would help to mention that the actual use case here is so that a client doesn't see the gap between one of their ids and the next to give them an idea of how much business we're doing. It's not necessarily a huge deal, but it'd be better if it were opaque.

Comment: Please, check this reference to know how to apply a constrain to a sequential id:    
  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526982/invoices-have-the-same-number-when-generated-at-the-same-time-in-node-js-how-to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this unless your INSERT acquires a table-lock. The reason is that the INSERT must figure out what's the max value so far for the respective company you're insert a row for. The row with that max value could be anywhere in the table. And the INSERT has to search for it while preventing any other INSERT from running concurrently, or else you have a race condition.

This table-lock behavior is not supported by INSERT to an InnoDB table. InnoDB can do an auto-increment that allows for concurrent INSERTs only because it tracks one max value per table and it only increments, it doesn't move backwards or "undo" incrementation.

MyISAM supports a feature of increment-per-distinct-value when using a compound primary key. After all, MyISAM already does a table-lock for INSERT or other updates. In my opinion, this feature is not enough of a justification to use MyISAM.

As @sgeddes commented above, the value of doing this is questionable anyway. What do you do when gaps appear, for example if you delete a row or if an INSERT is rolled back? Do you have to renumber the primary key, potentially updating thousands of rows? Do you try to insert subsequent rows into the gaps? This would require another table-lock, searching for the gaps and blocking other inserts while you do that.

Basically, keep this rule in mind: **The primary key is not a row number.** Don't treat it like one. The primary key is required to have unique values—but not consecutive values.

---

Re your comment: No, you should not think of auto-increment numbers as having any meaning, not even the order of creation. For one thing, the order of auto-inc values is not always the order the rows are committed.

It's a good idea to take anything Rails tells you about databases with a grain of salt. The designers of Rails really, really wanted database development to be simpler than it is. Rails has done a huge disservice to developers over the past 10 years.

Comment: Is it not self evident that ids don't get reused just because you delete an entry? Perhaps I have too much of a Rails bias in my thinking here, but I see ids like a sort of non-time related timestamp that indicates the order of creation.

Comment: @TiggerToo - it's not. It's a unique identifier. It does nothing else except that, you can't reuse them, you can't fill in the gaps, you can't force it to increment per-company, you can't predict its value. All it does is give something unique to a row, in a concurrent environment where many connections "compete" for such a value. There's a solid reason why it behaves like this, and that reason is concurrency + performance and it's the only way to achieve such functionality. If you need something different, implement a procedure that enumerates your records somehow.

Comment: PS: Please, check this reference to know how to apply a constrain to a sequential id:      
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526982/invoices-have-the-same-number-when-generated-at-the-same-time-in-node-js-how-to