# Invoices have the same number when generated at the same time in Node.js. How to achieve uniqueness?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

in my Node.js application, I wanted to enable a functionality to generate PDFs with invoices. Everything works great until two or more people generate an invoice at the same time (on different machienes). They are then prompted with different invoices that have the same number, e.g. Invoice no. 355. This is the method that saves the invoice to MySQL (using Sequelize):

```
CCInvoice.max("invoiceNumber")
    .then(invoiceMaxNum => {
        if(isNaN(invoiceMaxNum)){
            invoiceMaxNum = 1;
        } else {
            invoiceMaxNum++;
        }

        CCInvoice.create({
            invoiceNumber: invoiceMaxNum,
            invoiceNetPrice: parseFloat(report.finalNetPrice),
            invoiceVAT: parseFloat(report.finalVAT),
            invoiceGrossPrice: parseFloat(report.finalGrossPrice),
            invoiceDate: new Date(Date.now())
        })
            .then(...)
            .catch(...)
```

The primary key is id and it is auto_increment, the value goes every 10 numbers (because I'm using ClearDB on Heroku). Because I had to begin issuing the invoices starting from the number around 350 (previous invoices were issued manually) and because the id grows by 10, there is no easy correlation between the id and the invoice number.

Unfortunately, only one column can be auto_increment in MySQL. I'm not sure how to ensure uniqueness for all requests, regardless of how many there are. Let me know if you have some ideas.

Comment: Lock the table until a unique invoice ID has been generated, then release the lock?

Comment: I'll dig into doing that using Sequelize, thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the reference, I have used transactions in Sequelize and the code seems to be working. I tried generating the invoices from two different machines at the same time, and indeed they had two different numbers in a sequential order (400 and 401). The code that worked for me:

```
let transaction = await sequelize.transaction({ autocommit: false });

try {

    let { count, rows } = await CCInvoice.findAndCountAll({
        attributes: ["invoiceNumber"],
        transaction: transaction
    })

    // Since the numeration in the system does not begin from 0 but from 329
    let invoiceMaxNum = count + 328 + 1;

    let invoice = await CCInvoice.create({
        invoiceNumber: invoiceMaxNum,
        invoiceNetPrice: parseFloat(report.finalNetPrice),
        invoiceVAT: parseFloat(report.finalVAT),
        invoiceGrossPrice: parseFloat(report.finalGrossPrice),
        invoiceDate: new Date(Date.now())
    })

    (...)

    await transaction.commit();

} 
catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
    await transaction.rollback();
}
```

I am not sure whether this is the most efficient solutions but for now it seems to be working. If you have any suggestions or improvements, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a unique number, why don't you use the current timestamp or simply a UUID?

The numbers just need to be unique, or do they need to be sequential also? Or numbers that people can remember as well?

If it is just guaranteed unique, then your life is much simpler with uuids. Two lines of code and you're done.

Comment: I should have mentioned that, but as in the example Invoice no.  355, they need to be sequential so 356, 357 etc

Comment: Sequential numbering in a distributed system means locks. It's not trivial. Doesn't mean it has to be hard - but it's not trivial.

Comment: Current timestamp is not guaranteed to be unique, regardless of its granularity. You can fake it with a combination of procid and timestamp, but that's still dicey if the next procid is spawned during the same timestamp.

Comment: Yeah, it's not guaranteed, but if you are using microseconds, the changes of collision are very low.